# Ansible playbook needs to be run twice to mask a target

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat

I have a simple goal to disable and mask a target on my `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6` machine.

Here is my ansible .yml file;

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: 'Disabling sysctl ctrl+alt+delete'
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: ctrl-alt-del.target
        enabled: no
        masked: yes
        daemon_reload: yes
```

When I try to apply my playbook changes for the first time, the target is only `disabled`. It becomes `masked` only If I run the playbook again for the second time.

```
[root@dhcp-1234 ~]# systemctl is-enabled ctrl-alt-del.target
disabled
```

At this point I must say that I tested the same thing on a different machine but the OS version is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)` and I got the target as `masked` as I expected.

Also my ansible version is the same on both machines;

```
[root@dhcp-1234 ~]# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/usr/share/my_modules', '/opt/asml/ZXPFCF/ansible/modules', '/opt/asml/ZXPFST/ansible/modules', '/opt/asml/ZXPFST/lib/python']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2022, 11:04:20) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-7)]
```

So, What should I do to make my changes happen in one go on my Redhat 8.6 machine?

Comment: This might be caused and answered by Red Hat Solution #[1123873](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1123873). That single task seems not be enough according the documentation.